# VScode order of python imports: how to force tensorflow to import before keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, keras

I am importing several libraries in a .py file using VScode.

somehow it always orders the imports when I am saving the file.
It is important for me that a certain order is maintained, for example:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
```

should be before:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

which in turn should be before

```
import keras.backend as K
import keras
```

but even if I press `option`+`shift`+`o`, this order is lost after saving.

How can I force the order I need in this case, while generally keep VScode setting the order alphabetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable `Format on Save` in VSC's settings.

- Click Files > Preferences > Settings
- Type `format` in the search box
- Disable `Format on Save`

Comment: thanks. is there a way to make it a "one time" or "exception" ? so that normally it is formatting on save, but not in this case?

Comment: @ArieAI I don't believe so, sorry

Comment: @ArieAI You can disable this setting, use the format manually, and finally adjust the codes and save it.